# Cat5e slow but Cat6 makes things fast -- why?

Tags: networking

I ran a Cat5e cable from the GigE switch through my cellar to a wall plate, then connected to a PC. Speedtest showed about 94mbs speed.

Then I got a 50 ft Cat6 cable, an Amazon Basics thingie, ran it from the same switch, up the stairs and around to that same PC.

Speedtest showed about 350mbs speed.

Comcast Xfinity shows our service at about 350mbs so seems like the Cat6 cable to the GigE interface on the PC motherboard is about at max speed.

The question -- what's wrong with my Cat5e connection that it drops down automatically into the 100mbs speed?

I have other Cat5e runs in the house, also in the 100mbs range so would like to figure out what's going on since AFAIK the Cat5e cable should be able to run at GigE speeds for my short runs in the house.

Thanks.

Comment: The CAT5e cable can run at 1 Gbit/sec.  So I would be suspicious about proper cable ends and wall plate connections. Since any Ethernet cable is a form of transmission line, imperfections at the ends can cause this.

Comment: Does your Cat5e cable have all 4 pairs connected, as opposed to just two?

Answer (score 2):

Your in-wall Cat5e probably has a termination problem. Either you didn't get all 8 conductors fully connected, or you had a split pair. Note that cheap pinout testers can't detect a split pair. Fluke will happily sell you an expensive tester that can [detect a split pair](https://www.flukenetworks.com/knowledge-base/cableiq/ethernet-split-pair-error-detection-cableiq).